# OpenCV: Why are HoughCircles() not giving correct results?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to make a simple program to detect a circle in an image. I've written this code, and the result can be seen in the attached picture. Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
import time 
import cv2 
import imutils 
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('circle.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
binary=cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cv2.imshow('binary',binary)

circles=cv2.HoughCircles(binary,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,50,50,30,5,100)

if  circles is not None:
    circles=np.round(circles[0,:]).astype("int")

    for i in circles:

        cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),4)
        cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

else:

    print"no circle" 

cv2.imshow('circle',img)
k=cv2.waitKey(0)

if k==27:

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfqCe.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Have you tried varying the parameters in `cv2.HoughCircles()`? Check them  [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d)

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the parameters. I changed the last two parameters and now I am able to detect the circle. But I don't understand the meaning of these two parameters (min_radius and max_radius). The radius of my circle is 95. But to detect the circle correctly, my min_radius has to be between 7 and 27 and max_radius has to be between 0 and 95 otherwise I get results similar to the picture above, or no circles at all. Can someone explain this to me?